# i want to add one value to one value in one row in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

i have this code in sqlite

```
self.cursor.execute('update inventory set cost=cost+? where account=?',(value,account))
```

i just want to sum the `value` to the `cost` just in one row what ever if that was the first row or last, but the problem is when i `execute`, it sum the value to all rows that have the `account` name

just to know it don't have any error it just issue in the code

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: See section 2.3 of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: @Barmar the Optional LIMIT and ORDER BY Clauses in the UPDATE statement are supported only by custom builds of SQLite (with SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option).

Comment: @forpas I wasn't sure whether that option is typically enabled.

Comment: the true answer is to use `limit 1 `

Comment: `LIMIT` in the UPDATE statement is not supported by SQLite. You can use it only if you have built SQLite with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` compile-time option: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to get the max `rowid` of the `account` that you want and update only that:

```
UPDATE inventory 
SET cost = cost + ? 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM inventory WHERE account = ?);
```